# In DART, Is overriding the "==" and comparing both ojects' fields the only way to know if two objects are equal based on their values?

Tags: dart

Does dart have a built-in way that one can compare two objects based on their fields values without overriding "==" in the class.

I have a class with 20 fields and I want two objects of that class to be equal only when values in all fields are the same for both objects.

```dart
class Items {
  final String? field1;
  final String? field2;
  final String? field3;
  //...................
  final String? field20;

  Items({
    this.field1,
    this.field2,
    this.field3,
    this.field20,
  });

  bool operator ==(Items other) {
    return (field1 == other.field1 &&
        field2 == other.field2 &&
        field3 == other.field3 &&
        field20 == other.field20);
  }
}
```

Is this the only way to accomplish that in dart? What if I have 100+ fields? How can I avoid all these comparisons?

Comment: I recommend looking into a package like `equatable` (https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) if your `==` method are going to be as simple that you are making it here.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm going to look at it.

Comment: I looked it at. Yes, that's what I wanted. Thank you for recommemding it 

Comment: Great. I have made an answer you can accept if there is no further questions.

Comment: Also, always override hashCode if you override ==.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your equal method is rather simple, as suggested by your example, you use a package like [`equatable`](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) which is designed to make it simple for creating data classes with easy `hashCode` and `==`:

By using `equatable`, you just need to tell `equatable` how it can fetch your properties.

```dart
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Items extends Equatable {
  final String? field1;
  final String? field2;
  final String? field3;
  //...................
  final String? field20;

  Items({
    this.field1,
    this.field2,
    this.field3,
    this.field20,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        field1,
        field2,
        field3,
        //...................
        field20,
      ];
}
```

It can even make a `toString()` method for you if you add this to your class:

```dart
  @override
  bool? get stringify => true;
```

```dart
void main() {
  print(Items(field1: 'hello', field2: 'world'));
  // Items(hello, world, null, null)
}
```

Comment: This did exactly what I intended to do. Thanks alot.